# What to check when buying a used device

Tags: hardware

I'm thinking about buying a used Android device and I want to know what should I check on the device before I buy it?

Is there an app or something that does some sort of testing on the phone?

Are there any problematic parts that I should check?

Comment: Like what? I assume you'd do a factory reset, so really all you need to check is that all the hardware works. Make sure the screen looks good, try all the buttons, and take a shot with the camera.

Comment: Well, I hoped that there might be an app out there that can do that testing for me...

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to check for water damage.

> Every phone that is sold by a reputable retailer
>   (T-Mobile, Cingular, Verizon, Sprint, etc.) should contain a tiny
>   indicator that clearly shows if water has attacked your phone. This
>   little item is typically called the **liquid damage indicator**, or LDI
>   for short. In almost every case, **a red or pink indicator means that
>   there is water damage. A white indicator means that there is no water
>   damage**.

[Here](http://www.ehow.com/how_4479971_check-cell-phone-water-damage.html) is the detail.

Answer (score 6):

You also might want to check with Voodoo CarrierIQ detector if this device is clean. Besides, I also bought a used one and when you manage to reset it you should be fine. Type *2767*3855# for this if the password is no longer available. If your password for resetting is still available (e.g. if the previous owner knows it) there is no need for this combination obviously.

Comment: I didn't understand why I should type *2767*3855# what will this do?

Comment: It is possible to remove the CarrierIQ if rooted...

Comment: @kfir It's one of the Android Hidden Codes, which you can use to check if your phones features work corectly https://www.xda-developers.com/codes-hidden-android/

Answer (score 4):

The other answers cover some device specific things to check for, or fixable software issues. I'd take a different approach - check the hardware basics (screen, audio, buttons) and equally important - get on the phone with your carrier before buying to make sure the device can be activated - not blacklisted as lost/stolen, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

Some Samsung Galaxy S2 units that have outdated firmwares may have yellow tints on the LCD. This is not a sign for alarm; just upgrade the firmware and everything will be fine. In case the yellow tint is still there after a firmware upgrade, consult with Samsung Service Center to have it checked or replaced. (Yellow tint: [Samsung Galaxy S2 - Screen Problems](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hCfxCdtgxVw))

Pink camera spots were an issue too, but seems to have been fixed by firmware upgrades. Again, check with Samsung if it cannot be fixed by firmware upgrade.

I guess the only thing you need to check is if the basics works - camera, radio, 3g, wifi, sms, bluetooth, etc. (Camera spot: [Samsung Galaxy S2 Camera Pink Spot Problem](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJ-14AeaHqo))