# Yellow tint on S4's screen

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, screen, hardware, samsung-galaxy-s-4

The phone's screen has an annoying yellow tint. Is there any app that can fix gamma correction ? Or shall I return the phone and get another one ? Anyone else has this ?

This picture is from [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2263961&page=2) and explains my problem :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds reminiscent of a "feature" that's present on the S III. Try going into the **Settings**. In the **Device** section, click **Display**, then in the **Screen** section, click **Screen mode**. You probably want to change it from **Dynamic** to **Standard**.

(Some of these things might be named differently on the S4, in which case please edit the new names into this answer.)

Comment: THanks for replying. I have tried changing all those, plus the auto adapt feature, and the auto tone etc ... Nothing is working and the phone still has a yellow tint.

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to the yellow tint issue with the S2 before? Then, it's probably a hardware issue.
Related post: [What to check when buying a used device](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18326/what-to-check-when-buying-a-used-device)

In the link you gave, I would think that Light_Addict's issue is hardware-related. See if your shop will replace it. Try to compare it with other existing phones of the same model, using the same setting; you might want to do a factory reset so they'll believe you there's a difference in color.

Comment: Thanks for replying. The retailer has a batch with yellow tinted S4s .. They didn't believe I had a problem. I had to go to another store for extra comparisons and managed to find a difference. I'm going in for a second round of arguing soon.